# Windows Store Apps: Style TargetType="Page" not being applied

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps

I have tried to create a Style to apply to any Page (like a Master Style) to include a little watermark in a corner, but this kind of style doesn't work.

```
<Style x:Key="WatermarkPageStyle" TargetType="Page">
    <Setter Property="Template" >
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Page">
                <Grid>                          
                    <ContentPresenter/>
                    <TextBlock TextAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" FontSize="25" Foreground="Blue" Text="Watermark"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

What's the problem? Is there a workaround?

Comment: Could you show some code maybe?

Comment: Added the XAML fragment :)

Comment: can you post the xaml code of your page?? The first 5 lines of <Page ...

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft [employee says](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/bb927601-2e3e-45ac-afe8-621df57b9738/why-does-style-targettypepage-not-work-in-an-application?forum=winappswithcsharp) that this is a known issue and you should set these values locally.